# Javascript Refactoring - Elegant ways to implement ES6 classes

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, oop, refactoring

I am refactoring my project classes. I am not a pro with JS, that is why I ask here, to more experienced programmers with this language.

Until know I was doing this:

```
    class Person {
        // Constructor
        constructor(name) {
            Object.asign(this, {
               name,
            })
        }

        // Getters
        get name() {
            return this.name;
        }
    }

    // Main class methods
    Person.prototype.sayHello = function() {
       console.log("Hello world");
    }
    ...
```

But when I do:

```
const person = new Person("alex"); 
console.log(person.name); // This works... but...
```

My code editor (VS Code) doesn't detect the property "name" of the object person. Instead, if I do:

```
        // Getters
        getName() {
            return this.name;
        }
       
        ...
        console.log(person.getName());
```

the code editor autocomplete, detecting the getName() method of the object.

The same thing happens when using Object.assign in the constructor. My editor only detect the members if I do this.name = name...

Also, I don't know if I am going good attaching all the main methods to the prototype...

I remember (maybe I am wrong) that with functional classes, you got a better performance doing this, avoiding the methods recreation when creating a new intance.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getter is returning getter, not some internal value.

```
class Person {
    constructor(name) {
        this._name = name;
    }

    get name() {
        return this._name;
    }
}
const person = new Person('Victor');
console.log(person.name); // Victor
```